# List to Jquery Datatable c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, list, datatables

I'm trying to make my List to fill my jquery Datatable but I'm unable to do so, at the moment im writing my list to a file to access it by datatable in my `view-model` is my approach the correct one?

This is my code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in db.Pos)
{
   var total = 0;
   decimal costo = 0;

   for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
   {
      var value = 0;
      if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; costo = costo + item.Total; }
      total += value;
   }

   list.Add(item.Descripcion);
   list.Add(item.Pdv);
   list.Add(item.Rid);
   list.Add(((costo / (total + 1)).ToString("C")));

   for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
   {
      var value = 0;
      list.Add(value.ToString());
      int month = item.Fecha.Month;
      if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; list.Add(value.ToString()); }                                                
   }

   list.Add(total.ToString());
   list.Add((((costo / (total + 1)) * total).ToString("C")));
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<object>() { list });
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\path.txt", json);
```

And my Datatable Ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var table = $('#pftable_hdr').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "/path.txt",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    scrollY: "500px",
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 3
    }
  });
});
```

Part of my Txt File Output:

```
[["ENS FRUTAS","REST","CENAS","$26.50","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","$26.50","CAFE AMER ILIMIT","REST","CENAS","$11.50","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","$11.50","QUESADILLAS TRAD (2)","REST","CENAS","$25.50","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","$25.50"]]
```

How can I fill my Jquery datatable with my list? My text file should have `[]` before and after the `$data` but I can't make that happen only at the first of the file and in the end.

Comment: So you want ["ENS FRUTAS","REST","CENAS","$26.50","0","1"]["ENS2","REST","CENAS","$26.50","0","1"]..... ?

Comment: exactly, so my datatable displays them correctly @Rigin

Comment: I will put one answer .. try that code. Cant write that here, may get confuse

Comment: You should have a list of lists. and then serialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend code should look something like this. By doing this it will build a JSON string that is looking like this: `[["","",""...],["","",""...],["","",""...]]`

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var item in db.Pos)
{
    List<string> listItem = new List<string>();
    var total = 0;
    decimal costo = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        var value = 0;
        if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; costo = costo + item.Total; }
        total += value;
    }

    listItem.Add(item.Descripcion);
    listItem.Add(item.Pdv);
    listItem.Add(item.Rid);
    listItem.Add(((costo / (total + 1)).ToString("C")));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        var value = 0;
        listItem.Add(value.ToString());
        int month = item.Fecha.Month;
        if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad;    listItem.Add(value.ToString()); }                                                
    }

    listItem.Add(total.ToString());
    listItem.Add((((costo / (total + 1)) * total).ToString("C")));
    list.Add(listItem);
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\path.txt", json);
```

Comment: i tryed to use your code but i get a error on this part:

Comment: NVM got it and my file now saves exactly as i needed thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 list.Add("[");
 list.Add(item.Descripcion);
// rest code....

list.Add((((costo / (total + 1)) * total).ToString("C")));
list.Add("]");
```

Will this work for your case ? Let know your comment

Comment: If additional sq braces , then remove by substring

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<object>() { list });
```

In the above line list is already an object, then why you are creating a new object and assigning "list" to that object.

Try like below,

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

This will provide you the required result